# Dressing gown vs housecoat

Tags: history, language-evolution

As far as I can tell they refer to the same thing (bathrobe).

I'd like to know the roots of both, and if possible the history of their evolution. Specifically if the usage is influenced by social class, if possible?

EDIT:

From OED:

**housecoat**: A woman’s long, loose, lightweight robe for informal wear around the house.

**dressing gown**: A long, loose robe, typically worn after getting out of bed or bathing.

However I have mostly heard this used interchangeably.

Comment: Why, why, why would you want to know something so almost wilfully arcane as that, I wonder?

Comment: This is a history question not a language one. For the origin of words you can look here - http://www.etymonline.com/  - or in a good dictionary.

Comment: I think *housecoat* is usually lighter material that tends to have a button or zip front. American women wore them as *overalls* in the 60s & 70s to avoid getting their "real" clothes dusty/dirty doing housework. The social class that wore them probably employ a Latino housekeeper today. Men (esp, *Brits*) and ambulatory hospital patients wear *dressing gowns*, which are often heavier material, and have a tie-cord fastening at the front. They protect modesty, not the clothes you're wearing underneath.

Comment: Did you even make a head fake toward a dictionary before asking here?

Comment: Are you talking about *bathrobes*?

Comment: My impression, mainly from watching old British movies, is that the terms are rather vague.  About all you know, absent context, is that it's a robe of some sort, and if it's a "dressing gown" it's probably snootier.

Comment: I am an old Brit (though not in the movies and not snooty) and I wear a dressing gown every day. It's what I put on as soon as I get up and have breakfast, before getting dressed into my usual daily clothes. I also put it back on after getting undressed at night before eventually disrobing to get into bed. Women who clean, dust or polish (*lazy stereotype) wear a "housecoat" to do this job. Men never (*lazy generalisation) wear housecoats. YMMV

Comment: House dress is another name for house coat. Second hand copies of [The House Dress: a story of eroticism and fashion](http://www.amazon.com/House-Dress-Story-Eroticism-Fashion/dp/8831795252) can be picked up cheaply through Amazon. There is plenty of online information on your subject area and Wikipedia is a good place to start looking.

Comment: Hmm... bath robe, dressing gown, house dress seem to me a continuum of synonyms where the two ends are decidedly not synonyms. A bathrobe you put on to walk from the bathroom to your room, is often damp, and is often made out of terry cloth; male, female, child will wear it, associated with more luxurious living. A house dress (which I am not very familiar with in the real world) is for cleaning up around the house, and is primarily for a mom, and if I understand the media, associated with lower socioeconomic circumstances.

Comment: Dressing gown (halfway inbetween?) is a gown for dressing? You would wear a housecoat after having dressed and a bathrobe for before dressing, and a dressing robe for _while_ dressing?

Comment: I had never heard of a "housecoat" until I moved to Canada, I'd always called the garment I wear before getting dressed a "dressing gown". I think you could use it interchangeably with bathrobe but I always think of terry cloth as the material for bath robes, everything else in the same shape is a dressing gown.

Comment: There's as answer forming in these comments, to which I'll make no contribution, but let me introduce and compare _'smoking jacket'_ to _'house coat'_ in two senses.  Firstly they're both odd to to our modern perspective, but they make sense historically.  _'Smoking jackets'_ were worn by gentlemen to who retired after dinner to smoke cigars and performed the function of keeping the stink out of their formal dinner wear, and _'house coats'_ protected against dirt the 'good' clothes of ladies not so well heeled as to be able to afford servants, in a time before vacuum cleaners and other aids.

Comment: A bathrobe is not the same as a housecoat or dressing gown. The main difference is in the fabric. A bathrobe is expected to soak up water, the others are not. A bathrobe is essentially a towel in the shape of a robe (and is made of the same fabric, or at least fabric that is functionally similar). I wouldn't be surprised if people have wrongly started using these interchangeably (as dressing gowns and house coats are not common enough anymore to make a big distinction), but that does not make it correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a dressing gown is just what you wear over your pyjamas or nightie to keep warm, and to be more modest in the house. It is not the least bit "snooty". English and Australian people are very familiar with dressing gowns. A bath robe is an American term, but probably for the same kind of thing. I have had dressing gowns that do up with a tie, and ones with buttons, too. I have had terry towelling, silky, and woollen dressing gowns. As for house coat, I am not sure, but I think it is/was for ladies to wear mostly around the home during the day, not of a heavy material because it was a coat for inside the house! Another item to be considered is the bed jacket: shorter in length, lighter in material, and often worn while sitting up in bed reading, or if you were sick. 
P.S. House coats were also apparently called "dusters".

Comment: An American "bathrobe" is generally a fairly plain robe designed to fit over a nude body, or one wearing only lightweight pajamas.  I envision a woman's "dressing gown" (which I've only seen in the movies) as being a bit more elaborate, and more like a house dress.  As portrayed, the dressing gown presumably fits over the corset and slip that will eventually be under the more formal dress.  (A "house dress" is simply a frumpy dress worn around the house -- the equivalent of old jeans and a tee-shirt.)

Comment: I wear a dressing gown to and from my bath every morning. I am pretty sure it is the same garment that an American would call a _robe_ or _bathrobe_.

Answer (score 0):

Housecoat usually has buttons or zip to wear over your nightwear during the day

Dressing gown usually tied round your waist with a belt to use before bed or after bathin

Answer (score 0):

UK. A housecoat is (or was) a sleeveless wrap-over style lightweight garment usually with a floral print worn by housewives to do cleaning and washing chores. It is by no-means confined to a "class" but is probably more identified with the working class. Hilda Ogden, a character from the Soap Coronation Street was hardly ever seen without one. As the tendency for 'housewives' to go to work increased, so the use of housecoats died out, rarely to be seen today.

Answer (score 0):

ETA:  In case it wasn't clear and not sure it matters: I'm a 60ish old lady, lol. I just read this again after reading a comment and realized that name might be ambiguous, too, regardless of the "i" ending. The dressing gowns I wear aren't fluffy, lazy ephemera.  Mine are made of materials like vintage men's, but in a feminine cut/style. Silk, satin, rayon, even polyester and all are lined for warmth.

I love wearing dressing gowns and I'd love for the beautiful ones to make a comeback in fashion. I've been buying vintage and sewing my own. Men wore dressing gown, too. Watch old movies and see men wearing dressing gowns after coming home and taking off suit coat. You'll see them wearing shirts, ties, pants and shoes (or slippers sometimes).

Comfort and style without changing completely out of your "street clothes". Same goes for women (me) get home, take off office wear and put on dressing gown for comfort. They're modest enough to answer the door, but comfortable and relaxed without being sloppy. Even the most expensive bathrobes look like a bath robes.  I wear them around the house in cold weather. I wear leggings and tops and the house gets cool and I don't want to bundle up or wear a coat or bathrobe, so my dressing GOWNS are perfect! Men in dressing gowns: fictional characters Sherlock Holmes, Hercule Poirot, actors prissy Clifton Webb, suave David Niven, sexy, elegant and manly William Powell, Cary Grant - seriously, check out old movies. The men even wore them after taking off tux jackets.  In now way, shape or form does a bathrobe equate to a dressing gown for either men or women.

Women, wear a dressing gown after putting on your underwear and stockings to keep warm and feel pretty while putting on makeup/hair and before putting on outer street clothes.

Men or women get home from work, take off street clothes, but leave on undergarments, put on dressing gown, eat dinner, have drink (whatever) then get dressed for evening festivities inside or going out again.

A dressing gown is not what I wear to clean protect my clothes while cleaning the house, that would be a housecoat or housedress if I wore one.

Comment: Modulo drag queens, men haven't worn gowns in centuries. :)

Comment: @tchrist I have never heard the expression 'modulo' and googling has got me nowhere. Brief explanation for an ignoramus ?

Comment: @NigelJ Discounting or factoring out. OED: *prep.* b.  In extended use.  (a) With respect to an equivalence defined by (some feature), disregarding differences indicated by (some unimportant feature);  (b) taking into account (a particular consideration, aspect, assumption, etc.).

Comment: @tchrist modulo graduations, hospital wear (both patients and surgeons), ... ;o)